# Change blank selection in drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a databound dropdown list on my page.  The first value in the selection list is blank.  Is there a way that I can change it so that the first selection says "Unassigned" instead of blank?  I've tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
        // Insert 'Unassigned' value for artist dropdown
        ddlArtists.Items.Insert(0, "Unassigned");
```

After inserting the above code, the list still appears unchanged, with the first selection value being a blank.  Any pointers would be great!  Thank you!

EDIT:  Here is the code for the dropdown:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArtists" runat="server" Width="130px" TabIndex="5"
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlArtists_SelectedIndexChanged"
 DataSourceID="sqldsArtist" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" 
 OnDataBound="ddl_DataBound"
 AutoPostBack="True">
```

Comment: how you bind the data? Try adding item to the data source.

Comment: Can you post the bits from the `aspx` file?

Comment: How the ddl is data bound? And when do you insert this default value, before or after data binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do it on the CodeBehind. Just do it like that:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArtists" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Unassigned" Value="0" Selected="true" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The `AppendDataBoundItems` property defines whether the contents of the `DropDownList` should be cleared out before data binding.
Don't forget to check for a `PostBack` when you're data binding it, to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Although be careful, as I think this means performing a second databind (for whatever reason) will *append* to the results of the original bind.

Comment: Couldn't find anything on the MSDN regarding a second databind. But there's no harm on double checking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the SelectedIndex property of your DropDownList to 0.